# Generate directive content dynamically on ngclick

Tags: angularjs

I have one table. in that i have declared my custom directive

```
<table ng-show="dataset.length" ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="server in $data" ng-class-odd="'odd-row'" ng-class-even="'even-row'">
            <td width="30" class="text-center">
                <i class="ion-plus-round **toggle-icon**" group-row></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

While clicking on **toggle-icon** class

i need to generate one more tr data in next row.

custom directive is

```
app.directive('groupRow', function(){

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
         transclude: true,
        controller: 'groupRowDirCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/templates/group-row.html',
        link: function( scope, element, attrs, groupRowDirCtrl ) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                $compile(el)(scope);
                element.parent().parent().after(el);
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller('scrollableTableviewDirCtrl',
    function($scope) {
});
```

data have to fetch it from html page and append into next row.

How to do this?

Comment: It seems that part of your question is the answer.

Comment: It is not working. after loading content from html. i need to append into element.parent().parent().after(el);. here how can i get el

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly, the on click function is in the directive.

so, i would add a service for the **$data** array that is being repeated, and on click add another item to that array by using the service.

like so

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  dataService.setData([1, 2, 3]);

  $scope.data = dataService.getData();
});

app.directive('dir', function(dataService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<tr><td ng-click="addMore()">One More</td></tr>',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.addMore = function() {
        dataService.addRow();
      }
    }
  }
});


app.service('dataService', function() {
  var _data = [];
  var _service = {};
  var _cb;

  _service.getData = function() {
    return _data;
  }


  _service.setData = function(data) {
    _data = data;
  }

  _service.onUpdate = function(cb) {
    _cb = cb;
  }

  _service.addRow = function( /* attibutes here */ ) {
    _data.push({});
    if (angular.isFunction(_cb)) _cb();
  }

  return _service;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <dir ng-repeat="d in data"></dir>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```